# Getting result only when click submit for second time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular-changedetection

I'm trying to do change password feature in angular 7,

from the backend side, if the current password not correct, it will return true.

and in angular side error message will appear.

but the problem is i have to click twice to show the error message, even i can see the response in logs printing true value, but not sure why the *ngIf not working

Template side

```
    <span *ngIf="hasError">
         wrong current password value  
    </span>
```

my component side

```
hasError: boolean;

 submit () {
     this.apiService
    .changePassword(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.hasError = res;    });
```

service side

```
  changePassword(body: any){
     return this.http.post<any>(this.url + 'changePassword', body);
  }
```

can someone explain why i have to click submit button twice to show the html element

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have passed `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the component decorator. In this case, the angular will not read the changes until the next change detection cycle which in your case occurs on the second click.

In order to fix this, you need to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor and call the change detection cycle manually. Something like:

```
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  
  hasError: boolean;

  submit () {
     this.apiService
    .changePassword(this.formGroup.value)
    .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.hasError = res;    
       this.cdr.markForCheck();  // <<<---- detect changes
  });
```

Though there is no harm in using ChangeDetectorRef, another way to fix this problem is by using observables and angular async pipe.

```
  hasError$: new Subject();

  submit () {
    this.apiService
    .changePassword(this.formGroup.value)
    .subscribe(res => this.hasError$.next(res));
```

in template:

```
  <span *ngIf="hasError$ | async">
       wrong current password value  
  </span>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but do we think there is other way i can rewrite my code to reach changeDetection on push ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason for your issue

`hasError: boolean;`

You are initiating the variable but not giving any value at the starting. So as soon as the component is loaded, the value of hasError is undefined/null. So it will load the template with that value only.

How to prevent this:

Method 1) (not preferred)

```
// If you dont want to initiate the value in the component.ts file, make this change in 
  the HTML file, 

<span *ngIf="!!hasError">
         wrong current password value  
</span>


the '!!' will check for null status of the variable
```

Method 2) Preferred

```
// Initiate the value of the variable to false, 

// In component.ts file

hasError: boolean = false; // IMPORTANT

and then your code remains the same. 

So the initial value will now be false, and also when the service is subscribed, you can have it true or false and your HTML also remains the same.
```